# Given three circles (not concentric) if a variable circle cuts all three circle at equal angles.Then the locus of center of variable circle?

Tags: circles

Given three circles (not concentric) if a variable circle cuts all three circle at equal angles.Then the locus of center of variable circle?

I don’t know how to find locus without assuming the equation of three circle.

Comment: A diagram might help explain this question. Thanks.